# android - Displaying the item clicked to a Listview populated by SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-cursor

Good Day everyone!

I am new to android programming, struggling on how to attach _id of database to the listview adapter. Its almost consume as whole trying to figure out on how to do it.

---

Here's the code for list:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fadein, R.anim.fadeout);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dictionarylist);

    filterText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtsearch);
    ListView itemList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(Dictionarylist.this);
    String[] terms = dbHelper.dictionaryWords();


    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,terms);
    itemList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    itemList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Dictionarylist.this, DictionaryActvity.class);

            intent.putExtra("DICTIONARY_ID", position);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    filterText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            Dictionarylist.this.listAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
    }
```

---

Here's the code for Database Helper:

```
public class DBHelper extends DBCon {
public DBHelper(Context context){
    super(context);
}

public String[] dictionaryWords(){
    String query = "Select * from main_dictionary";
    Cursor cursor = this.getdbconnection().rawQuery(query, null);
    ArrayList<String> wordterms = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            String word = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("main_word"));
            wordterms.add(word);
        }
        while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    String[] dictionaryWords = new String[wordterms.size()];
    dictionaryWords = wordterms.toArray(dictionaryWords);
    return dictionaryWords;
}

public Quizzer getQuizById(int quizId){
    Quizzer quizzer = null;
    String query = "select * from main_dictionary where _id =" + quizId;
    Cursor cursor = this.getdbconnection().rawQuery(query, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do{
            String word = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("main_word"));
            String tagdef = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("tag_definition"));
            String engdef = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("eng_defintion"));
            String sample = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("example"));
            quizzer = new Quizzer(word, tagdef, engdef, sample);
        }
        while(cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    cursor.close();
    return quizzer;
}
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Where getting `attach _id` from db?

Comment: Nope. I would like to attach the _id of the database to the listview so when we click the item on the listview, it should display the info from _id of database.

Comment: That app is a dictionary by the way.

Comment: Problem solved or still looking for solution ?

Comment: Still looking for a solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK inside RecyclerView's `onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)`, you may want to attach `holder.setTag(model.getId)` instead of holder.setTag(position) that we do. Take an `OnClickListener` outside by `holder.setOnClickListener(exampleListener)` and get that tag inside `View.OnclickListener` by using `int positionId = (int) holder.getTag()`. This way you may utilize RecyclerView too.

Comment: Should I use recyclerview instead of listview?

Comment: You may want to if you need. RecyclerView gives much more options for customisation.

Comment: You also may write a custom adapter for the ListView and do the same, for that refer:  [link](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter)  Also for RecyclerView tutorial go through this: [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll try your solution later.